# Skype: How to make it text chat only?

Tags: skype, chat

I would like that my Skype contacts can contact me over text chat only. 
Is that possible? If so - how to set that up?

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean, exactly? Do you want contacts not being able to call you, is that it?

Comment: Exactly. No call and no webcam chat, just text chat.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a third party application that supports Skype chat. I use Trillian; it supports many protocols including Skype Chat, GTalk, Yahoo Messenger, Facebook chat, and more.